# How to deal with presence or not of xml namespaces using xslt

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have some XML/TEI documents, and i'm writing an XSLT 2.0 to extract their content.

Almost all TEI documents has no namespace, but one has the default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"`). 
So all documents has the same aspect, with unqulified tags like `<TEI>` or `<teiHeader>`, but if I try to extract the content, all works with "non-namespaced-documents", but nothing (of course) is extracted from the namespaced-document.

So i used the attribute `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"` and now (of course) the only document working is the namespaced one.

I can't edit documents at all, so what I'm asking is if there's a way to change dynamically the xpath-default-namespace in order to make work xpaths like `//teiHeader` both with namespaced and non-namespaced documents

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a more practical solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **XSLT 2.0**, then you do have the option for a wildcard match for the namespace in a node test.

e.g. `//*:teiHeader`

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#node-tests

> A node test can also have the form
>   *:NCName. In this case, the node test is true for any node of the principal
>   node kind of the step axis whose local
>   name matches the given NCName,
>   regardless of its namespace or lack of
>   a namespace.

This is functionally equivalent to Dimitre Novatchev's example, but a little shorter/easier to type.

***However, this will only work in XSLT/XPATH 2.0***.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a clean way to do precisely what you are asking. However, there are workarounds available. You could use a two stage process whereby you strip the namespace from the document if it's present and then pass it through the same templates for all content.

There is a good example (in XSLT 1) of doing this in the [DocBook XSLT](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/). Take a look at html/docbook.xsl and common/stripns.xsl

Basically, you would need to assign the result of stripping the namespace to a variable and then call your existing templates (for the non namespaced) content but select the variable.

Answer (score 1):

**It is ugly, but this gives you what you want**:

```
//*[name()='teiHeader']
```

**If you use this style for all location steps in any XPath expression, the XPath expressions will select elements only by name**, regardless whether or not the elements belong to any namespace.